# FieldCondition in an EntityQuery for media is causing a website error

Tags: entities

This entityQuery in a theme preprocess function in Drupal 8 is working great:

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('media')
    ->condition('status', 1)
$result = $query->execute();
```

But as soon as I add this fieldCondition for a boolean field, I get a website error:

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('media')
    ->condition('status', 1)
    ->fieldCondition('field_flagged', 'value', '1', '=');
$result = $query->execute();
```

What is wrong in the above code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no `fieldCondition` method, `condition` works for all fields:

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('media')
  ->condition('status', 1)
  ->condition('field_flagged', 1);
$result = $query->execute();
```